# Leer correctamente el registro de un bautismo mexicano de 1744

Tags: identificación-de-término, escritura-manuscrita, genealogía

Quisiera correcciones a esta transcripción de un registro sacramental del año 1744. Hay dos puntos sobre los cuales no estoy de nada seguro, y espero resolver lo que dicen de verdad. "esp.s" puede ser cierto pero no sé lo que quiere decir. Así tengo la transcripción hasta ahora:

> En el año del S.r de mil Sett. Quarenta y q.tro en viente y cinco del Hen. **?????** de Cura bap.se Solemnem.te puso Oleo y Chrisma a un infante que nacio a diez y siete de dho. mes. a q.n puso por nomb.e Antt. Aug.n hijo leg.mo de D.n Aug.n Fernandez y de D.a Marg.ta de Fonseca Montenegro **esp.s?????** de esta villa. Fue su Pad.no Don Jph. Aramburu vezino de la ciudad de Queretaro. Se le advirtio lo dio puesto por el Santo Concilio y porque Conste lo firme.

Y aquí el original:

[image: registro sacramental]

Comment: La última frase creo que dice "Sele administró lo dispuesto por el Santo Concilio".

Comment: Está bien que "Transcríbanmelo" se excluye. Gracias -- esta comunidad ha contribuido mucho al uso mío de documentos históricos. La próxima vez colocaré identificación-de-término.

Comment: Related discussion on Meta: [Should we accept questions about identifying words in texts?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3238/1674)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como quedan fuera del ámbito del sitio las preguntas de tipo "corregidme mi texto", me centraré en los dos problemas particulares que planteas y que resaltas en negrita.

**¿Qué pone antes de "cura" en la segunda línea?**

Aquí tienes la misma expresión, extraída de la partida de bautismo de un antepasado mío nacido en 1793 en un pueblo de Albacete, España:

[image: Then.te de Cura]

La abreviatura corresponde a la expresión "Teniente de cura". Entiendo que se usa [*teniente*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ZTNdleM) en su acepción 6: "persona que ejerce el cargo o ministerio de otra, y es sustituta suya".

En el caso de tu partida es posible que la abreviatura sea ligeramente diferente. Parece que es *Ttth.e* o podría ser *Thth.e*.

**¿Qué significa la abreviatura *esp.s* de la quinta línea?**

A esas alturas de la partida, las frases usuales tras referir los nombres de los padres son:

- ... vecinos de esta villa...
- ... naturales de XXX y vecinos de esta villa...
- ... natural de XXX y parroquiano de esta iglesia...

Buscando un poco de información sobre a qué se puede referir esa abreviatura, me encuentro con que en partidas de bautismo de México se solía identificar si los padres eran españoles, en caso de que su procedencia fuera esa. Luego parece que el texto sustituye la fórmula "natural de" por:

> .. hijo legítimo de `<padre>` y `<madre>`, españoles, de esta villa...

Entiendo que se refiere a que eran españoles y residentes en la villa en cuestión.